# deploying angular to heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my angularJs app to heroku following this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-yeomanangular-app-heroku/

I've been able to get my app uploaded to heroku but unforunatly it doesn't seem to load any of my scripts.

```
https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/
```

When inspecting the page i get a bunch of 404 errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Running the app locally works fine. Unfortunately i have no clue where to look for a solution.

**update:**

these are all the errors from the page (which i think is all of the scripts from the index.html)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/scripts/app.js    
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/scripts/controllers/main.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/scripts/controllers/firebase-test.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/scripts/controllers/chart-test.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/scripts/services/data-services.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/scripts/controllers/sidebar.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) angular.min.js:36 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]               http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=DataDisplayP…s.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.0-beta.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://data-display-prototype.herokuapp.com/styles/main.css     
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**update 2:**

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "datadisplayprototype",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.12.3",
    "gzippo": "~0.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.10.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.2.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.31",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

**update 3: solved!**

The problem turned out to be the fact that i removed the comments in my index.html file that grunt uses to generate script files. As a noob i didn't suspect that comments could actually have a function and just removed them without thinking. Apparently Heroku knows to deploy the app from the dist folder. Since the dist folder was generated without any scripts, i got the errors.

Comment: does your project have a package.json?  Are you using bower to load stuff?

Comment: it has a package.json, and i think so. There are bower_components used in the application if that's what you mean and bower scripts. However the page is also unable to load non-bower scripts.

Comment: what are you getting 404 on?  add it to the OP...not all I guess, but some.  Does it seem to be stuff primarily installed by bower?

Comment: updated post with the errors

Comment: and you are certain that you have uploaded the scripts folder?

Comment: yes, all of the files in that directory are added to git and pushed to heroku. It feels like for some reason it's looking in the wrong directory but the paths seem to be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75944/discussion-between-tpie-and-mischa).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the bottom of your package.json should fix your bower issue:
If you check your install log, you should see it probably isn't even running bower.  I don't believe heroku checks for a .bowerrc.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  }
```

postinstall tells npm to run additional scripts or commands.  Because heroku will run an `npm install` when it finds a package.json, but not a bower install, this let's us get bower going once npm is done.

You have another issue here, I believe:

`app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));`

This is setting your site to reference the `/dist` directory, which is not where your app is.  Or, if you really want it to point to the `/dist` directory, try appending `../app/` to all your script references in your html file.